# Multi-part identifier could not be bound but no join issue?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm running the below on MS Server Management studio v11.02 
However' I'm getting an error saying that the:

```
The multi-part identifier "PO.LastPo" could not be bound.
```

Any ideas what I can do to solve this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT PO.LastPo
    INTO #IncludedPoll
    FROM
    (
            -- Inner query makes sure member was actually enrolled for 2 yrs
            SELECT LastPo, COUNT(*) AS Periods
            FROM [Cye].[2_output_lastPoll] PO
            WHERE PO.PollPq IN (1,2)
            GROUP BY LastPo
    ) A
    WHERE Periods IN (1,2) AND A.LastPo NOT IN (SELECT LastPo FROM #FilterPoll)
```

`#FilterPoll` is a temporary table, which I get fine and contains some IDs that I want to filter out of the `#IncludedPoll` temporary table.

I've looked at other answers around this but they all relate to joins, which should not be a problem here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You named your inner query `A`, so it should be `SELECT DISTINCT A.LastPo` instead of `PO.LastPo`